# database locked when using sqlalchemy to_sql method

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have a function to upload a dataframe to a SQL server, defined as follows:

```
def uploadtoDatabase(data,columns,tablename):

    connect_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};Server=ServerName;Database=DatabaseName;Encrypt=yes;Trusted_Connection=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes')
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={connect_string}', fast_executemany=False)

    # define data to upload and chunksize (max 2100 parameters)
    requireddata = columns
    chunksize = 1000//len(requireddata)
    
    #convert boolean columns
    boolcolumns=data.select_dtypes(include=['bool']).columns
    data.loc[:,boolcolumns] = data[boolcolumns].astype(int)
    
    #convert objects to string
    objectcolumns=data.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
    data.loc[:,objectcolumns] = data[objectcolumns].astype(str)

    #load data
    with engine.connect() as connection:
      data[requireddata].to_sql(tablename, connection, index=False, if_exists='replace',schema = 'dbo')
      connection.close()

    engine.dispose()
```

I have tried different options but every time I execute this insert (4M records, which takes a while), the database is locked. Other processes are waiting on the Python process to finish.

Is there any way to ensure other database transactions continu to execute while this function is running, other than creating a for loop and execute the function multiple times on smaller batches of the data?

Comment: If the communications link is slow and uploads are taking a while... have you considered using `to_sql()` to upload to a staging table and then transfer the data to the final table once it's all up on the server?

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that the entire database is locked, or is it just the one table that you are replacing?

Comment: the whole database seems to be locked since I See processes waiting on the python proces id in sql activity monitoring. the other processes have nothing to do with the specific table. even expanding the table list is frozen in SSMS untill I kill the python proces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even expanding the table list is frozen in SSMS untill I kill the python proces

You're using `if_exists='replace'` so you've dropped and recreated the table in the transaction.  This gives you an exclusive metadata lock for the duration.

If you want to do this concurrently, create all the tables ahead-of-time, at design time, or at runtime in a separate transaction.  Then `append` the data.

Comment: I added:
```connection.execute(sa_text('''TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.''' + tablename + '''''').execution_options(autocommit=True))```

Why does the engine keep that lock for so long? Does it mean it uses a ```SELECT INTO``` to create the table, instead of first a ```TABLE CREATE``` and then an ```INSERT INTO``` ?

Comment: The lock is held until the end of the transaction.